# how to maintain code for two sdk versions of windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am building an app for windows phone sdk 7.0 and 7.1, I want to have some extra features for 7.1, but I want to maintain only one code base for both, and only have some code appear if user's phone is 7.1.

I read about Shawn Wildermuth's post: http://wildermuth.com/2011/08/23/Maintaining_a_Project_with_Two_Windows_Phone_Versions. But I am not sure how to do "First off, I took my original project and created two solution folders and created the 7.1 projects as shown here" mentioned in the post.

Could someone help? or suggest other ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Updated 11/5/2011: removed outdated information about the Marketplace. Thanks for the udpated info @johnforrest]

To do what Shawn is describing take your existing solution with your existing 7.0 project(s). Add a solution folder and name it "7.0". Move your existing 7.0 projects into that solution folder. Make another solution folder named "7.1". For each project in the 7.0 solution folder, create a new matching project in the 7.1 solution folder. These are Shawn's PhonyTools.7.1 and so on. Now follow his directions for populating the 7.1 projects with linked files that are linked from the 7.0 projects.

I find linked files to be a blessing and a curse. If you open the linked file in one project and edit it, Visual Studio does not alway know that the other project containing the linked file needs to be rebuilt. Lately, I've been finding that if I remember to then open the linked file in the other project I will get a warning that the file is opened in another project, but then VS recognizes that the file has changed and will rebuild the other project.

Preprocessor directives, as suggested by @KevinDTimm, don't solve the problem all by themselves, because you still need two different projects for the two different types of projects (7.0 and 7.1 apps or libraries). Additionally the different versions of the apps will reference different corresponding versions of assemblies.

Lastly, while we're on the topic of conditional compilation, don't forget the [Conditional](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) attribute, which is often a much better solution than using preprocessor directives. Bill Wagner gives a good description of the merits of the [Conditional] attribute in Effective C#, 2nd ed., item 4, p. 20. Enjoy!

Comment: This is no longer true. MS has added support for submission of separate 7.0 and 7.1 versions for the same app. This blog post outlines the details: http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2011/09/20/submit-windows-phone-7-5-apps-today-update-7-0-apps-in-october.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the update @johnforrest. I missed that announcement but it is welcome news! I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Guys. @VisualStuart, I am using visual studio express and it doesn't have solution folder capability. But I managed to do that using two solutions and have 7.0 project in one and 7.1 in the other. It works.

Answer (score 1):

The perfect solution is preprocessor directives